# Measuring time taken for each function in WPF GUI without using StopWatch

Tags: c#, wpf, performance

I wanted to measure the time taken for each function to execute in a WPF application. When I browse through the internet, the answer I get is to use "System.Diagnostics.StopWatch" class.

I have 1000s of functions. It's very hard to programmatically add the Stopwatch statement before calling a function and get the elapsed time.

After browsing, I got to know about the Visual Studio Performance profiler and I used it.

However, the timings displayed in the profiling data and the time at which the GUI is loaded in real time is different

I used a physical stopwatch to measure the GUI load time by running the exe and starting the stopwatch.

I used a prototype app in which I will populate 5000 TextBox controls programmatically.
In the stopwatch, I measured 3.85seconds for me to see the screen. However, the profiler gives a different data. This is snapshot of the profiling data [Please check this out.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HK5M.png)

Can any one help me out in finding the reason for the difference?

I need to find the GUI load time and the time taken for each function for optimizations.

Is there any open source tool available to do this??

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score -2):

U can try Datetime.now when starting programm and using datetime.now when the event or whatever is started. Then u calculate the difference between this 2 values.